# How can I display the convex polygon?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to ask the user to input the number of shapes and the point coordinates that the convex polygon should appear but for some reason it won't draw in the window. Would appreciate some advise!

```
while (window.isOpen())
    {   
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
        {
            window.draw(convex[i]);
        }

        if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Escape ) )
        {
            window.close();
        }


        window.display();
    }
```

Comment: You edited your post after reading the answer below but... is it working now?

Answer (score 3):

You draw, then clear, then display. That won't work. You need to clear the old frame first, *then* draw and *then* display.

```
    window.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
    {
        window.draw(convex[i]);
    }

    window.display();
```